# How to set up accounts LAN jabber chat server?

Tags: server, windows, lan, jabber

How can I implement a jabber chat server on ubuntu with clients on windows?

Server part is almost installed as per jabber and Ubuntu guide how to create users account and authenticate them using mysql.

How are clients enabled and configured to authenticate and join on the server. Does anything need to be done for the DNS part?

Comment: Since your question is related to the windows clients install and setup on windows I am not sure there is much we can help you with here. That will depend on the client application being used and the with the Windows platform.

Comment: Might be a better question for http://superuser.com/ since you aren't really asking about Ubuntu so much as cross-platform Jabber setup.

Answer (score 1):

Hey friend, I use Iptux for chatting on my home LAN.  Setup is quite simple.  Merely install the client on each desktop (no server software needed the clients detect each other.)  Iptux also includes file sharing capabilities.

On the ubuntu / debian based linux client machines use sudo apt-get install iptux

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/iptux  (appears to have been in the "universe" repositories since karmic)

On the windows client machines install ipmsg.exe  (Iptux is a linux version of the windows ipmsg client or maybe the other way around.)

http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en

Also, be sure to open port 2425 on the firewall of each machine (and router if necessary) as that is the port that iptux / ipmsg uses.

Answer (score 0):

`IPtux` has a considerably better interface than `ipmsg`. The latter doesn't show the conversation, only individual messages. Both suffer from splitting into three windows, when on big window would be better, and toolbars please.

Works OK though, Ubuntu 11.10 - Ubuntu, Ubuntu - Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

The best way implementing LAN jabber chat server is with **Openfire** server, it is simplest jabber server that can be configured on web interface very easily. It depends on sun java so here is simple tutorial with picture how to install Openfire and java to work on 12.04 : [Install Openfire chat server communicator on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 | Linux migration tutorials](http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/setup-openfire-communicator-on-ubuntu.html)